# Binding not updated immediately inside updateUIView in UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I am adapting a Swift Project to SwiftUI. The original project has Drag and Drop on UIImages, drawing and some other manipulations which aren't possible in SwiftUI.

> The code below is for explaining the problem only. Working code on: 
>   https://github.com/rolisanchez/TestableDragAndDrop

On the project, when a user clicks on a button, a `@State setChooseImage` is changed to true, opening a sheet in which he is presented with a series of images:

```
.sheet(isPresented: self.$setChooseImage, onDismiss: nil) {
                        VStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.setChooseImage = false
                                self.chosenAssetImage = UIImage(named: "testImage")
                                self.shouldAddImage = true
                            }) {
                                Image("testImage")
                                    .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.original))

                                Text("Image 1")
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                self.setChooseImage = false
                                self.chosenAssetImage = UIImage(named: "testImage2")
                                self.shouldAddImage = true
                            }) {
                                Image("testImage2")
                                    .renderingMode(Image.TemplateRenderingMode?.init(Image.TemplateRenderingMode.original))
                                Text("Image 2")
                            }
                        }
                }
```

After selecting the image, `setChooseImage` is set back to false, closing the sheet. The Image `self.chosenAssetImage` is also a `@State` and is set to the chosen Image. The `@State shouldAddImage` is also set to true. This chosen UIImage and Bool are used inside a UIView I created to add the UIImages. It is called inside SwiftUI like this:

```
 DragAndDropRepresentable(shouldAddImage: $shouldAddImage, chosenAssetImage: $chosenAssetImage)
```

The UIViewRepresentable to add the UIView is the following:

```
struct DragAndDropRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var shouldAddImage: Bool
    @Binding var chosenAssetImage: UIImage?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> DragAndDropUIView {
        let view = DragAndDropUIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: DragAndDropUIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext< DragAndDropRepresentable >) {
        if shouldAddImage  {
            shouldAddImage = false
            guard let image = chosenAssetImage else { return }
            uiView.addNewAssetImage(image: image)
        }
    }
}
```

> I understand `updateUIView` is called whenever there are some
>   changes that could affect the views. In this case, `shouldAddImage`
>   became true, thus entering the `if` loop correctly and calling
>   `addNewAssetImage`, which inserts the image into the UIView.
>
> The problem here is that `updateUIView` is called multiple times, and
>   enters the `if shouldAddImage` loop all those times, before updating the `shouldAddImage` Binding. This means that it will add the image multiple times to the UIView.
>
> I put a breakpoint before and after the assignment of `shouldAddImage = false`, and even after passing that line, the value continues to be `true`.
>
> The behavior I wanted is to change the `shouldAddImage` immediately to false, so that even if `updateUIView` is called multiple times, it would only enter the loop once, adding the image only once.